# How to derive this matrix trace formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, trace-map

I am trying to derive equation (7) from [this physics paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.50.1870) (sorry for the paywall)

$M_n$ for $n\geq 0$ is a sequence of $2\times 2$ real matrices with determinant $1$. These matrices obey the following recurrence relation for $ i\geq 1$:

$$M_{i+1}=M_{i-1}M_i$$

From this we may obtain

$$M_{i+1}+M_{i-2}^{-1}=M_{i-1}M_i+M_{i-1}M_i^{-1}$$

Let $x_n$ be the half-trace $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}(M_n)$. Apparently by taking the trace of the equation above we get the recurrence relation on the half-traces:

$$x_{i+1}=2x_ix_{i-1}-x_{i-2}$$

But I can't figure out how to do the derivation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
with $\det A = 1$, then
\begin{align}
A^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
So the trace are the same.

**Edit:** Note, by direct calculation, we see that
\begin{align}
BA + BA^{-1} = B(A+A^{-1})
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
A+A^{-1} = \operatorname{tr}(A) I.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks- I am also having trouble with how to get the $2x_ix_{i-1}$, since the trace of a product of matrices is not, in general, equal to the product of the traces.